# I am trying to authenticate with facebook but getting error TokenError: Malformed auth code

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, facebook-authentication

I am trying to authenticate user with facebook login using passport.js. I am able to login to facebook then I get the below error

TokenError: Malformed auth code.

```
app.get('/facebook',passport.authenticate('facebook'));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,    
    callbackURL: "facebook/redirect"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("authenticated");
  }
));

app.get("/facebook/redirect",passport.authenticate("facebook"),function(req,res)
{
    console.log("hey");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a trailing slash to the redirect URI

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,    
    callbackURL: "facebook/redirect/"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("authenticated");
  }
));
```

Comment: That was solved. Now I'm getting Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request                     But facebook doesn't allow to put localhost uri in redirect uri ox

Comment: what about 127.0.0.1:port?

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your help @Chris. I was using the wrong callbackURL. Corrected url is: **/facebook/redirect**

Comment: ah okay forward slash on the beginning than.  I read on github that it failed without the end one.  I'm glad you figured it out.